# How do I use Javascript to modify the base URL of a website to a custom one with the path?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For example, I want to turn:
https://google.com/A7239J
into...
https://example.com/google.com/A7239J
I want to be able to do this within the browser, using Javascript.
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn’t this be a significant security risk and open a huge hole for phishing attacks if this *was* possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to fetch resources using that URL as the base URL, then you can use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element:

```html
<!-- every URL will be relative to this value -->
<base href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/">
<img src="./4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" width=300>
<img src="./c/cf/Black_hole_-_Messier_87.jpg" width=300>
```